# Delimited query not listing all values

Tags: stored-procedures, sql

Thru SP i am trying to get all the product id from the product table....in the below format:  prod1,prod2, prod3, prod4....etc. but it is not listing all the product id from the table. Here is my SP:

```
create procedure spGetAllProductID
@productcode varchar(500) output 
as
BEGIN 
 BEGIN TRY 
  declare @DelimitedString varchar(500)
  Select  @DelimitedString = isnull(@DelimitedString + ',','') + Productid
  from prdtable
  Select @DelimitedString 
  set @productcode=@DelimitedString 
 END TRY
 BEGIN CATCH  
  SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() as ErrorNumber, ERROR_MESSAGE() as ErrorMessage  
 END CATCH  
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be because your string is at varchar(500) and it is truncating at 500 characters so will omit the later product codes. What about being bold and using varchar(max) for your variables/parameters?